# Windows 10 changes Microsoft account actual name to email

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, homegroup, microsoft-account

**Hi!**

This is a weird one.

After logging into my Microsoft account (not using local account), in approximately ~30m my name changes from my actual name to my @outlook.com email address. It's shown in the login screen and int the settings app, under "*Your info*". Its visible even in Control Panel / Users.

I can get my name back if I logout from Microsoft Account using "*Sign in with a local account instead*" option, logging out and signing in again, but the whole process repeats every time.

- It should look like this [image: Should look like this]
- But it looks like this [image: But looks like this]

This is super annoying. It also affects HomeGroup.

I've tried to update my actual name to something else from Microsoft Account page, hoped that it would trigger a name update, but had no luck.

I want my real name to stay and Microsoft account to be connected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's your question?  You should disconnect the MS account, this allows you to create a new local profile with the directory name you want, then link that profile to the MS account.  When asked to create a local account be sure you don't use what is suggested otherwise you will continue to have this problem

Comment: His question is how to get Windows to not “forget” that his account also has a real name set.

Comment: Yes! Thats the question. I want my real name to stick.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by searching through the registry for my email and changed all places that had FirstName, LastName, FullName, Initials values empty and filled them with data. Worked.